# Elasticsearch aggregations for faceted search excluding some fields

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation, faceted-search

I have shop which use elasticsearch 2.4 for faceted search. 
But at the moment the existing filters (product attributes) are taken from mysql. I want to do this using elasticsearch aggregations.
But I got the problem: I do not need to aggregate all the attributes.

What a have:

Part of Mapping:

```
...
'is_active' => [
    'type' => 'long',
    'index' => 'not_analyzed',
],
'category_id' => [
    'type' => 'long',
    'index' => 'not_analyzed',
],
'attrs' => [
    'properties' => [
        'attr_name' => ['type' => 'string', 'index'     => 'not_analyzed'],
        'value' => [
            'type' => 'string',
            'index' => 'analyzed',
            'analyzer' => 'attrs_analizer',
        ],
    ]
],
...
```

Exemple of data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "is_active": "1",
    "category_id": 189,
    ...
    "price": "48.00",
    "attrs": [
      {
        "attr_name": "Brand",
        "value": "TP-Link"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "Model",
        "value": "TL-1"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "Other",
        "value": "<div>Some text of 'Other' property<br><img src......><ul><li>......</ul></div>"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "is_active": "1",
    "category_id": 242,
    ...
    "price": "12.00",
    "attrs": [
      {
        "attr_name": "Brand",
        "value": "Lenovo"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "Model",
        "value": "B570"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "OS",
        "value": "Linux"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "Other",
        "value": "<div>Some text of 'Other' property<br><img src......><ul><li>......</ul></div>"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "is_active": "1",
    "category_id": 242,
    ...
    "price": "24.00",
    "attrs": [
      {
        "attr_name": "Brand",
        "value": "Asus"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "Model",
        "value": "QZ85"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "OS",
        "value": "Windows"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "Other",
        "value": "<div>Some text of 'Other' property<br><img src......><ul><li>......</ul></div>"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Attributes such as "Model" and "Other" are not used when filtering products, they are only displayed on the product page. On the other attributes (Brand, OS, and others ...) I want to receive aggregations.

When I try to aggregate the `attrs.value` field, of course I get aggregations for all data (including the large "Other" fields, in which there can be a lot of HTML).

```
"aggs": {
    "facet_value": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "attrs.value",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
```

How to exclude `"attrs.attr_name": ["Model", "Other"]`?

Change the mapping is a bad solution for me, but if it is inevitable, tell me how to do it? I guess I'll need to make "attrs" nested?

**UPD:**

I want to receive:
 1. All the attributes that the products have in a certain category, except for those that I indicate in the settings of the my system (in this example I will exclude "Model" and "Other").
 2. Number of products near each value.

It should look like this:

For category "Laptops":

Brand:

- Lenovo (18)
- Asus (19)
- .....

OS:

- Windows (19)
- Linux (5)
- ...

For "computer monitors":

Brand:

- Samsung (18)
- LG (19)
- .....

Resolution:

- 1360x768 (19)
- 1920x1080 (22)
- ....

It's **Terms Aggregation** , I use this for the number of products for each category. And I try it for `attrs.value`, but I do not know how to exclude "attrs.value", which refer to "`attrs.attr_name": "Model"` & `"attrs.attr_name": "Other"`.

**UPD2:**

In my case if map attrs as nested type, the weight of the index increases by 30%.
from 2700Mi to 3510Mi.
If there is no other option, I'll have to put up with it.

Comment: depending on what kind of metrics you are interested in you may have to change your mappings. as your data model has many association for attrs. you have to look at nested data type https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/nested.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to map first attrs as [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/mapping-nested-type.html) and use [nested aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html).

```
PUT no_play
{
  "mappings": {
    "document_type" : {
      "properties": {
        "is_active" : {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "category_id" : {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "attrs" : {
          "type": "nested", 
          "properties": {
            "attr_name" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "value" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


POST no_play/document_type
  {
    "id": 3,
    "is_active": "1",
    "category_id": 242,
    "price": "24.00",
    "attrs": [
      {
        "attr_name": "Brand",
        "value": "Asus"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "Model",
        "value": "QZ85"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "OS",
        "value": "<div>Some text of 'Other' property<br><img src......><ul><li>......</ul></div>"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "Other",
        "value": "<div>Some text of 'Other' property<br><img src......><ul><li>......</ul></div>"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Since you didn't mention how you want to aggregate.

Case 1) If you want to count the attrs as individual. This metric gives you count of term occurrences.

```
POST no_play/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nested_aggregation_value": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "attrs"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "value_term": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "attrs.value",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST no_play/_search
    {
      "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "nested_aggregation_value": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attrs"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "value_term": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "attrs.value",
                "size": 10
              },
              "aggs": {
                "reverse_back_to_roots": {
                  "reverse_nested": {
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Now to get count of root document with attrs value you will need to hook a [reverse nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) to move the aggregator a level up to the level of root document.

Think of the following document.

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "is_active": "1",
    "category_id": 242,
    "price": "24.00",
    "attrs": [
      {
        "attr_name": "Brand",
        "value": "Asus"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "Model",
        "value": "QZ85"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "OS",
        "value": "repeated value"
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "Other",
        "value": "repeated value"
      }
    ]
  }
```

For first query the value count for 'repeated value' will be 2 and for second query it will be 1

**Note**

here is how you can do filtering to exclude

```
POST no_play/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "nested_aggregation_value": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "attrs"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "filtered_results": {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must_not": [{
                                "terms": {
                                    "attrs.attr_name": ["Model", "Brand"]
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "value_term": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "attrs.value",
                                "size": 10
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


POST no_play/_search
 {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "nested_aggregation_value": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "attrs"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "filtered_results": {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must_not": [{
                                "terms": {
                                    "attrs.attr_name": ["Model", "Brand"]
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "value_term": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "attrs.value",
                                "size": 10
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "reverse_back_to_roots": {
                                    "reverse_nested": {}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. But in my case if map attrs as nested type, the weight of the index increases by 30%.
from 2700Mi to 3510Mi. This is an estimate.
If there is no other option, I'll have to put up with it.

Comment: i don't see any reason for you not to have a nested data type for attrs. As they reperesents one to many relationship. Also at the same time i look at fields inside attrs, i.e "attr_name", "value", look like they reperesent attr key-value pair. could have better to model them has single json object , i.e '{"attr_name_1": "value1","attr_name_2":"value2"}', as they look like json object, as you are also not interested in attr_name in this particular usecase.

Comment: I had time to work on this problem again. And I'm again at a dead end. Using your code, I get aggregations in the "value" field from all the "attrs" records. How can I exclude from the result those records in which "attrs.attr_name" == "other"? Or "attrs.attr_name" == "model"?

Comment: anyway how this worked till now? i will be happy to help always

Comment: Until this time it worked like this:
To get all the attributes (brand, OS, screen resolution, etc.) for faceted search in the store, I chose from the elasticsearch ids of all products from the selected category. And I searched these ids in the sql database in the table, which links the product to its attributes. And from sql got the necessary set of attributes.
I could not make the aggregation by attributes through the elastic.
And I'm very grateful for your help.